# Running VirtualBox on a Windows 8.1 host

Tags: linux, virtualbox, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit machine, with an Intel Haswell i7 processor, and 8GB of RAM.

I installed the latest VirtualBox (4.3.6) and I'm trying to install a Linux guest. I've tried several Linux distribution ISOs (Mint16, Mint16-xfce, Fedora20, Kubuntu13.10), and they all get stuck right after the Live CD boots. I managed to install some of them on my VirtualBox on the Mac, so it's not the ISOs fault. Something is preventing the boot sequence. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to do the 64-bit or 32-bit Linux guests? Is virtualization turned on? What is the EXACT CPU model? Can you load a version of Windows on VirtualBox?

Comment: I'm trying 64-bit for the guests. Virtualization is turned on. CPU model is I7-4500U. Haven't tried Windows on VBox, but managed to install Linux on Hyper-V 9reason I'm not sticking to Hyper-V is the resolution limit).

Comment: Try with a 32-bit guest, just for S&G

Comment: Do you have a hunch? I never had that problem before with VBox (as said I have a Win7 machine happily running Ubuntu64, as well as a Mac doing the same) so before I start downloading more ISOs, I wonder if there's something I may be missing.

Comment: It's going to be the first thing I'd try. I never allocate more than 3GB of RAM anyways to my VMs, so I never use the 64-bit ISOs (except for testing purposes).

Comment: Fair enough - I'll give it a try and report.

Comment: Spent hours downloading 32-bit Kubuntu. Now getting following error: "piix4_smbus ... SMBus base address uninitialized. Upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr" - never seen that before. For the record, standard Ubuntu VM, with 2GB RAM.

Comment: Weird... What cpu options are set on the vm?

Comment: Default ones - any change crashes the machine on boot. But after reading around, it seems that this error (and the several that follow) can be safely ignored. I managed to reach the installer, so I guess 32-bit is a go. How much memory does a 64-bit VM require, in your opinion?

Comment: I see no reason to use less than 4gb on 64 bit, whether it's a vm or physical machine

Comment: No go on 32bit - way to slow (20 minutes to boot to desktop) - either Windows 8.1 or the latest version of VBox are screwed up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12245/discussion-between-canadian-luke-and-traveling-tech-guy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the answer. It all hinges on Hyper-V and the fact that it's enabled by default in Windows 8.1 Pro (as well as in other Pro and server Windows versions). With Hyper-V running, other hypervisors (like VirtualBox, VMWare and Android emulator) are crippled.

You could, potentially, disable Hyper-V from the Windows Add/Remove Features dialog. But what if you use Hyper-V for development or testing (i.e. WP8 development)?

The solution is to boot Windows with Hyper-V turned off. And the easiest way to do it, is to create a new boot configuration, with Hyper-V off, and boot to it whenever you need to use VirtualBox.

There are several step-by-step guides on how to create a new boot configuration - [this one](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx) has some screen shots.