# VirtualBox on Windows 8.1 - revisited

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, hyper-v, hypervisor

Back in 2013 I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/695056/running-virtualbox-on-a-windows-8-1-host), and based on the answer, created a new "no hypervisor" boot setting for my new laptop. The problem is, even after booting into a setting with no hypervisor, VirtualBox machines don't work, and the "acceleration" tab is off. Further more, hypervisor still seems to be on.

Here's my `BCDEdit` dump showing `hypervisorlaunchtype` is Off:

```
Windows Boot Loader

identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             No Hyper-V
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {89e2e51a-d733-11e4-99f4-f310b841d4f8}
integrityservices       Enable
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {89e2e516-d733-11e4-99f4-f310b841d4f8}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Off
```

And here's my `coreinfo -v` dump, showing that hypervisor is still on:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel
Microcode signature: 00000019
HYPERVISOR      -       Hypervisor is present
VMX             *       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             *       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)
```

Has anything changed in the settings since 2013?

Comment: No;  You still have to boot with hypervisor turned off.  Does it work if you remove the Hyper-V feature?

Comment: Do I actively have to remove the feature? How come booting with Hypervisor off not working? - that's my real question.

Comment: **It should work.**  It was working when you submitted that answer I would guess.  I only asked if it worked if you uninstall the feature to verify doing disables the hypervisor.  There has been no changes to Windows 8.1 since you submitted your answer that would explain the reason it stopped working.  Really there have been no significant changes to Windows 8.1 except Update 1 ( Spring 2014 ).

Comment: I suggest copying the normal (current) entry and modifying it so `hypervisorlaunchtype` is set to off.  I know this might not work.  But it is worth a try.

Comment: That's what I did - I followed the steps in Scott's article, pointed to in the original answer. I copied the default setting, modified hypervisor, saved under a new name, and booted to it.

Comment: It worked when you original did it and now it doesn't.  Like I said nothing has changed.  Windows 8.1 hasn't had any real updates since they began testing on Windows 10 only security updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out creating a `bcdeit` setting and selecting it in the boot menu was not enough. I had to turn it to default setting. My guess is the boot menu moved so fast, I might have mis-selcted.

To turn you setting to the default one, I ran `bcdedit /v` to get the IDs of all available setting, and `bcdedit /default {insert ID of no Hyper-V setting}`.
After that, just reboot, and enjoy a hypervisorless Window. Now to solve the fact that fonts inside the VirtualBox VM look so tiny...